# Non-linear regression. Obtain B.spline coefficients using Fourier Transform?

Tags: nonparametric, nonlinear-regression, splines, fourier-transform

I came up with a idea to estimate the coefficients of a B-spline fit by using the Fourier Transform but I don't know if it makes any sense to estimate them in this way.

Given that

$$s(x)=\sum_kc(k)\beta^n(x-k)$$ where $k$ is an integer and $\beta^n(x)$ is defined as a ($n+1$) times convolution :$$\beta_0*\beta_0*\beta_0(x)$$ 
where $\beta_0$ is a rectangular pulse of length 1 centred at zero.

One could hence write $s(x)=(c*\beta^n)(x)$.
Applying the Fourier Transform we obtain.
$s(\omega)=c(\omega)\cdot\beta^n(\omega)=c(\omega)\cdot \beta_0(\omega)^{n+1}$

$$\beta_0(\omega)= (\operatorname{sinc}(\omega/2))$$
From here I would like to obtain $c(\omega)$ to then apply the inverse FFT.
I've seen some papers dealing with a similar methodology but without explaining in detail what are the condition in order for this to work.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: It's unclear how you would apply this approach: could you explain how it might work with actual data?